# Pular para section após selecionar option

Tags: javascript

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte: eu tenho um `select` com 5 `options`, quero que quando eu selecione, por exemplo, `option1`, vá para primeira `section`, quando eu clicar em `option2` vá para segunda `section`.

```
<select>
    <option class="primeiraOpcao">Brazil JS</option>
    <option class="segundaOpcao">Meetup CSSSP</option>
    <option class="terceiraOpcao">Freecodecamp SP</option>
    <option class="quartaOpcao">Front in Sampa</option>
    <option class="quintaOpcao">Front in BH</option>
</select>
```

E tenho as `sections` definidas assim

```
<section class="alinhamento" id="braziljs">
<section class="alinhamento" id="meetup">
<section class="alinhamento" id="freecodecamp">
<section class="alinhamento" id="frontinsampa">
<section class="alinhamento" id="frontinbh">
```

E tambem tenho meu codigo no JS, ainda apenas selecionei as options..

```
var primeiraOpcao = document.querySelector(".primeiraOpcao");
primeiraOpcao.textContent = "Brazil JS";

var segundaOpcao = document.querySelector(".segundaOpcao");
segundaOpcao.textContent = "Meetup CSSSP";

var terceiraOpcao = document.querySelector(".terceiraOpcao");
terceiraOpcao.textContent = "Freeecodecamp SP";

var quartaOpcao = document.querySelector(".quartaOpcao");
quartaOpcao.textContent = "Front in Sampa";

 var quintaOpcao = document.querySelector(".quintaOpcao");
 quintaOpcao.textContent = "Front in BH";
```

Estudo JS a alguns dias e queria conseguir fazer isso, mas to com duvida de como fazer..

Comment: Esse "vai para" seria mover a página até a `section` em questão?

Comment: Sim, a pagina está no topo, assim que selecionar move até a section!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, aconselho você modificar um pouco o seu `select` e adicionar um atributo em `options` referente a qual `section` você quer visualizar. Para atributos personalizados, utilize o prefixo `data-`. Por exemplo, podemos definir um atributo `data-anchor` em `option` para especificar para qual `section` deve ser movido:

```
<select id="choice">
    <option data-anchor="braziljs">Brazil JS</option>
    <option data-anchor="meetup">Meetup CSSSP</option>
    <option data-anchor="freecodecamp">Freecodecamp SP</option>
    <option data-anchor="frontinsampa">Front in Sampa</option>
    <option data-anchor="frontinbh">Front in BH</option>
</select>
```

Perceba que o valor de `data-anchor` é exatamente o `id` da `section` para qual quer visualizar e é muito importante que seja assim, caso contrário não funcionará.

Com o JavaScript, você pode tratar o evento `onchange` do `select`, obtendo o valor de `data-anchor` da `option` selecionada e definindo o valor de `location.hash` para este valor. Desta forma, na sua URL aparecerá a parte `#brasiljs`, por exemplo, movendo a página para o elemento cujo `id` é `brasiljs`.

```
const select = document.getElementById("choice");

// Executa quando uma opção for selecionada:
select.onchange = function (event) {
  // Obtém a opção selecionada:
  let option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  // Obtém o valor do atributo data-anchor:
  let anchor = option.getAttribute("data-anchor");
  // Move a página para o elemento desejado:
  location.hash = "#" + anchor;
}
```

Veja um exemplo: ao selecionar uma nova opção, você automaticamente será movido para a respectiva `section`:

```js
const select = document.getElementById("choice");

select.onchange = function(event) {
  let option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  let anchor = option.getAttribute("data-anchor");
  location.hash = "#" + anchor;
}
```

```css
.alinhamento {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<select id="choice">
  <option data-anchor="braziljs">Brazil JS</option>
  <option data-anchor="meetup">Meetup CSSSP</option>
  <option data-anchor="freecodecamp">Freecodecamp SP</option>
  <option data-anchor="frontinsampa">Front in Sampa</option>
  <option data-anchor="frontinbh">Front in BH</option>
</select>

<section class="alinhamento" id="braziljs">Brasil JS</section>
<section class="alinhamento" id="meetup">Meet Up</section>
<section class="alinhamento" id="freecodecamp">Free Code Camp</section>
<section class="alinhamento" id="frontinsampa">Front in Sampa</section>
<section class="alinhamento" id="frontinbh">Front in BH</section>
```